# Comparing File Dates in a Directory

Tags: python, datetime, ctime

I am trying to write a script in Python to upload a series of photos depending on the dates they were created. I am having an issue of comparing the dates of each of the files to a date before and after the dates I want so that I can create an array to loop through for my uploading. Here is what I have:

```
from stat import S_ISREG, ST_CTIME, ST_MODE
import os, sys, time, datetime

array = []

area = "/home/user/blah"
# Edit the path to match your desired folder between the ""
os.chdir(area)
retval = os.getcwd()
# Puts you in the desired directory

dirpath = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) == 2 else r'.'
entries = (os.path.join(dirpath, fn) for fn in os.listdir(dirpath))
entries = ((os.stat(path), path) for path in entries)
entries = ((stat[ST_CTIME], path)
           for stat, path in entries if S_ISREG(stat[ST_MODE]))

for cdate, path in sorted(entries):
    filedate = time.ctime(cdate)
    if filedate < datetime.date(2015,03,13) and filedate > datetime.date(2015,02,17):
        print time.ctime(cdate)
        print os.path.basename(path)
```

Is there a way to do this with ctime or is there a better way?

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ctime return the string representation, if you want to compare with time, you should compare the timestamp or datetime class.

```
for cdate, path in sorted(entries):
    # compare by timestamp
    #if cdate < time.mktime(datetime.date(2015,03,13).timetuple()) and \
    #    cdate > time.mktime(datetime.date(2014,02,17).timetuple()):

    # compare by datetime
    filedate = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(cdate)
    if filedate < datetime.datetime(2015,03,13) and \
            filedate > datetime.datetime(2014,02,17):
        print time.ctime(cdate)
        print os.path.basename(path)
```

Comment: Oh, cool I thought fromtimestamp would only work with timedelta. Cool, I just learned something. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's no real need to `os.chdir()` here. Dealing with absolute filenames is fine. You can simplify the selection criteria using a list-comp, `datetime`, `os.path.isfile` and `os.path.getctime`, eg:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime

files = [
    fname
    for fname in sorted(os.listdir(dirpath))
    if os.path.isfile(fname) and
    datetime(2015, 2, 17) <= datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(fname)) <= datetime(2015, 3, 13)
]
```

This returns a list of all files between two dates...

I'm guessing you're using Python 2.x because otherwise `datetime.date(2015,03,13)` would be giving you a `SyntaxError` in 3.x. Be wary of that as `03` is an octal literal and just happens to work in your case - but `08`/`09` will break as they're invalid for octal.